# It is possible to establish a VM-to-VM connection between Azure virtual machines?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, azure

How should I create and configure Azure virtual machines to allow VM-to-VM connections?

- It is possible to connect using the private ip?
- Do I need a Azure Virtual Network?

Basically I need to run some applications on each VM that need to talk to the other instances on the same azure subscription using TCP connection.

For now the only solution that I have found is to add the required endpoints and access the virtual machine using its public ip. There isn't a way to connect using the private ip? In this way it should be faster and with slow latency right?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMs *in the same Cloud Service* can connect to each-other out of the box. You can connect to a VM in the same Cloud Service via its hostname.

Please [see here for a detailed description](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/connect-to-a-cloud-service/).

So all you need to do is to make sure that your VMs are in the same Cloud Service.

Comment: Even when in the same Cloud Service, by default the VMs won't be in the same private subnet, so you'll have to allow the connections in the VM firewall's **public** profile.

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to connect using the private ip?

Yes, machines should be in the same Virtual Network

> Do I need a Azure Virtual Network?

Yes